# How do I click on a icon made with the following code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
<div class="search-toggle">
<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"/></i>
<div id="___gcse_0" style="width: 598px;">
</div>
```

I tried doing this way //(".//i[contains(@class, 'fa fa-search')]"))
for which I am getting an exception saying 
**org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException**: element not visible
But at the same time, the icon is being located in Chrome and FF with no problem.